# Change the server header with embedded tomcat

Tags: tomcat, server, header

I am using embedded tomcat 9.0.0.M6 in a java application. Tomcat add the header

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Note : I am not using Spring-Boot

How can I change the value of this Server header ? Should I override this header in my Servlet ? I did not find a parameter to override this configuration in the Tomcat API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

final Tomcat server = new Tomcat();
server.getConnector().setXpoweredBy(false);
server.getConnector().setAttribute("server", "Protected Server");
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.